# Price not being displayed on Magento 2.2.4 product page

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2.2.4, product-prices

I have an installation of Magento 2.2.4. I created a new configurable product but the price is not displayed in the frontend nor are the option.

If I create a simple product everything is alright.

Anyone can tell me why?

Comment: How  you added product, did you add size or color attribute with the product? Configurable product itself don't have any price , however each variation has its own simple/virtual products , each simple/virtual product that added/associated with the configurable product must  have price that would show for configurable product.

Comment: Also check the store view and run the re-indexing.